# Adding Comments and Votes to Community Bulletin Posts

Tags: feature-request, comments, community, community-bulletin

Not sure if this is the best place to request this feature, so please let me know if I need to move it.

In Community Bulletin (blog.stackoverflow.com), I suggest to add a couple of features that we have in StackExchange sites like:

- Users can comment with their StackOverflow/StackExchange profile,
  instead of entering their name and email.
- Users can vote up the blog posts. It would be better that comments
  like "Nice Job", and "Thanks" (for example look at [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/03/your-communities-list-is-now-customizable/?cb=1))
- It would be nice if users can vote up others comments. Then some nice ideas or criticisms will be bolder for the community members and StackExchange team.

Comment: The community bulletin is that thing you see on the right of this page, titled "Community Bulletin". I believe you are talking about the blog?

Comment: @Oded, yes I mean the blog. Since some blog posts shows up in the Bulletin, I got confused.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian, I think it would be nice for some blog posts like this (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/). Because, one can simply ignore the 'thanks' and 'nice job' comments and get the useful ones! That was a suggestion anyway :)